# File system access with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I already developed an internal app that lets the user pick a folder and then I do some magic to the files inside that folder. That has been built using standards (html/js) and hosted on an internal server.

Now, I need to:

1- Store the original path location somewhere (so, I need a way to obtain it)
2- Re-use that path so the user doesn't need to pick the same folder again.

I know this can't be done in a page and that's not the idea. I'm looking to build an extension (for the extended permissions), but so far in the documentation I found (for chrome, for example) that can't be done.

Am I right? Or is there a way to get the FULL path location of the folder, and later be able to pass it to a file input (or similar). I'm looking for a way to do it even if I have to restrict myself to one browser (as I pointed out, this is an internal app).

Comment: Your extension can use [nativeMessaging API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to communicate with a separate utility (e.g. a node.js script) that runs as an OS process thus being able to access the file system. Check out an example extension + python host in the documentation. There should be examples for node.js elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be what I need!!!.